# GLM com fator aleatório no R

Tags: r

Preciso fazer um glm no R, porém há dependência entre os dados. Me foi solicitado inserir essa dependência como fator aleatório na análise. Porém não estou conseguindo um comando para isso.

Panorama:
- GLM, binomial
- 2 variáveis resposta e 2 variáveis explicativas + fator aleatório.

Eu tentei isso:

```
modelo1<-glm(cbind(visitas,acertos)~cor_vantajosa*fase,random=~1|id,binomial(link="logit"),data=dados)
```

Qualquer ajuda é bem vinda!

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar a função `glmer` do pacote `lme4`.

No seu caso deve ficar assim:

```
modelo <- glmer(cbind(visitas, acertos) ~ cor_vantajosa*fase + (1 | id), data = dados, family = binomial)
```